# Very low sound in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

This question may have been answered before but I have not found an answer so sorry if it has been asked multiple times. Title pretty much says it all, my sound is very low when I installed ubuntu 13.04 on my toshiba satellite laptop, my sound was fine when I had windows but I decided to install ubuntu and run it with the lubuntu desktop environment and due to the extreme speed I decided to use ubuntu as my primary OS and remove windows. Anyway my sound is very low and it is on max and I made sure it is not muted in alsamixer, I've also used the PulseAudio volume control and that is also on max.

The sound is so low to the point that I can't hear it through my speakers except for a tiny bit once in a while, but I have to use my gaming headphones(Turtle beaches X12) and put the volume on max to hear sound, but it is still very low. Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed that the sound volume is lower than in windows for the same settings. After a little research I've found out, that pulseaudio bundle in ubuntu lacks of an equalizer. I found the equalizer for pulseaudio and installed it. Below I've put the package, I've used.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

After installation I restarted the computer (perhaps pulseaudio server restart is sufficient) and run the equalizer. I've selected laptop profile save the settings and voile, the sound is now much better.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [Ubuntu official SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) to the end of step 4. After restarting the computer the sound quality became comparable to that on windows.